# Обнаружение символа в php

Tags: php, html

Как можно проверить, присутствует ли определенный символ в значении переменной в php. К примеру, у меня есть переменная `$binding`, мне нужно проверить, есть ли в ее значении символ `'@'`

Comment: strpos() тащемта

Comment: $mail = strpos($binding, '@');
    $tel = strpos($binding, '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || '0'); Так нужно?

Comment: Я-то откуда знаю как вам нужно. Функция strpos определенно может сказать есть символ или нет в строке.

Comment: Для этих целей надо воспользоваться регулярными выражениями